# WPF: Exception if i add a eventhandler to a MenuItem (in a ListBox)

Tags: wpf, exception, listbox, contextmenu

i wanted a contextmenu for my ListBoxItems.
So i created this:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxName">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="View" Name="MenuItemView" />
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
```

This works great. I have the contextmenu for all items, but if i want to add a click-eventhandler to the menuitem, like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="View" Name="MenuItemView" Click="MenuItemView_Click" />
```

I get a XamlParseException when the window is created.

InnerException:
The Object System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem cannot be converted to type System.Windows.Controls.Grid

It throws only the exception if i add a event-handler. The event-method is empty.

Edit:
Stacktrace of the InnerException:

> at
>   Chat_Client.ChatWindow.System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(Int32
>   connectionId, Object target) in
>   c:\XXX\Chat_Client\ChatWindow.xaml:Row
>   19.
>
> at
>   MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetConnectionId(Object
>   root, Int32 connectionId, Object
>   instance)

Edit2:
Now i have to get the object I clicked with the contextmenu. First i tried this:

```
//MenuItem s = sender as MenuItem;
//ContextMenu cm = s.Parent as ContextMenu;
//Popup pu = cm.Parent as Popup;
//object o = pu.Parent;
```

But the Popup's parent is null.
Then i simply get the selectedItem from the ListBox. This works, but is there no way to get the ListBoxRow of the clicked Contextmenu?

Comment: What's the InnerException's StackTrace?

Comment: at Chat_Client.ChatWindow.System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target) in c:\XXX\Chat_Client\ChatWindow.xaml:Row 19.
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.SetConnectionId(Object root, Int32 connectionId, Object instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your crash with VS2010 and WPF4.

You only need one context menu for all your items so you can extract it to a window resource, for example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ListBoxItemContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="View" Name="MenuItemView" Click="MenuItemView_Click"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then change your setter to refer to that one context menu:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContextMenu}"/>
```

and the event handler then works:

```
private void MenuItemView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rick. I created a new demo-project to reproduce the error, but ne exception this time... However, the event got not triggered. (I had the Conextmenu defined in the listbox) After i extracted the Contextmenu to Windows.Ressources it worked! But why did it not worked when the contextmenu is defined in the listbox?